# How to make the shape of a parameter a variable?

Tags: openmdao

Suppose I'm optimising the number of wind turbines in a wind farm. The shape of the layout is a variable driven by the optimiser.
If I don't declare a shape or val in the parameter, I get the error:

`ValueError: Shape of output 'U' must be specified because 'val' is not set`

but, the shape of U depends on the size of the input parameter, which is unknown.

Should I build an external module to which the shape is written to by the optimiser and have my Component read the shape? Or is there a much simpler way? Thanks!

Comment: Can you formulate your problem so `U` is sized to the maximum possible size of the input?  Internally, you can have solve_nonlinear reshape it to the appropriate dimension at each call.  If it doesn't change size, that should be a relatively inexpensive operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it can't really be unknown. I would usually do this with an argument to the `__init__` method. When you're setting up your class you pass in the size of the variables you need (or some number that lets you compute the size of the class like n_turbines). I would do this in a subclass of Problem that you define.

The optimizer can't be changing the size of that input live. It must be fixed. If at some later time you want to change the size of the problem, just create a new instance of your Problem and pass in the new size. You'll just have to re-run setup, but that shouldn't be hugely expensive.

Comment: Congrats on the PhD Justin. Any updates to this answer by any chance? thanks!

Comment: Im happy to help, but I think I need a more concrete example. Can you construct a sample case we can use as a basis for discussion?